# AngularJS: Get value of element in custom directive

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code

```
app.directive('datepicker', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

            const format_datetime = '"Y-m-d H:i'
            const format_date = '"Y-m-d'
            var updateModel = function (dateText) {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(dateText);
                });
            };
            today = moment().format("dd/mm/yyyy")
            var options = {
                dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                onSelect: function (dateText) {
                    updateModel(dateText);
                }
            };
            elem.flatpickr({
                enableTime: true,
                dateFormat: "Y-m-d H:i",
                minuteIncrement: 1,
                time_24hr: true,
                onChange: function (selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
                    updateModel(dateStr);
                },
            })

        }
    }
});
```

When inspecting the code, this gets produced:

```
<input class="input-date-cell ng-pristine ng-valid ng-binding ng-not-empty ng-touched" ng-class="{'newRow': row.id == newRowIdEdit}" datepicker="" ng-model="row.start_date" ng-bind="row.start_date">2011-01-01</input>
```

What I am after is how would I get that date text? The reason being is that if the date has no colons, I want it to have one format for flatpickr. If it has colons in, I want another format.

Any suggestions?

I tried

```
console.log(ngModelCtrl.$viewValue);
```

However this logs `NaN` to console

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Had to issue `watch`

```
app.directive('datepicker', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "AE",
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            const format_datetime = 'Y-m-d H:i';
            const format_date = 'Y-m-d';
            var updateModel = function (dateText) {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(dateText);
                });
            };
            today = moment().format("dd/mm/yyyy")
            var options = {
                dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                onSelect: function (dateText) {
                    updateModel(dateText);
                }
            };

            var unregister = scope.$watch(function(){
                return ngModelCtrl.$modelValue;
            }, initialize);

            function initialize(value){
                ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(value);
                unregister();
                if (value.indexOf(':') > -1) {
                    console.log(value,format_datetime);
                    flatpickr_custom(true,format_datetime)
                } else {
                    console.log(value,format_date);
                    flatpickr_custom(false,format_date)
                }
                
            }

            function flatpickr_custom(enableTime,dateFormat){
                elem.flatpickr({
                    enableTime: enableTime,
                    dateFormat: dateFormat,
                    minuteIncrement: 1,
                    time_24hr: true,
                    onChange: function (selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
                        updateModel(dateStr);
                    },
                })
            }

        }
    }
});
```